# Change background color of single page in Google Document

Tags: formatting, google-docs

I would like to know how to change the background color of the cover page of a multi-page Google Document.

Comment: Google Docs have changed a lot since this question was posted by the other hand, this doesn't look as a good question for a site for power users of web applications --> Search thoroughly this site and the help center of the corresponding web app, in this case [Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs), show what you tried, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK there is no way to change the background color of a single page. The best workaround I can think of is to create a a table that is 1x1 and expand the cell to be as big as possible. You can then change the color of the cell to be whatever you want.

The downside here is that, well, it's a table, so already not ideal. There other thing is that you are constrained by the margins of the page, unless you want to change the margins for every page in the doc.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to change the background color of a single page !! This is how you do it:

*Select page setup from the file menu*
[image]

*Choose the color you want*
[image]

Color is set for a single page, but also set for the whole document.

If you print out the finished documents as PDF files, then you can use for example the following web app to merge the two documents: http://www.pdfmerge.com/.

Comment: "Color is set for a single page, but also set for the whole document." So in other words it's not possible to change the color for a single page.

Comment: Had to edit your answer. What a weird answer btw, it is NOT possible to change the color of a single page and leave the others as is. At least not yet.

Comment: @felix The answer is still super misleading. Please could you (or someone) correct this answer? I don't have enough reputation. It's one of the top search results and super frustrating that it's misinformation.

Comment: @Paul locked this question as obsolete and added a post notice to this answer. Please let me know if you are interested in making a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just make a separate doc for your cover page?  Or better yet, download your doc into a pdf and make a flipsnack or something for the paper.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to open MS Paint, make a rectangle with the colour you want, copy it into your document and format the image to stay behind the text.

Then you can expand the rectangle to fit the whole page or to whatever size you want.

Comment: How do you do that? I can't find options for putting the image behind the text nor for filling the whole page (it wants to stay within the margins).

Answer (score 3):

You can only change the page background color for the entire document (`File > Page Setup`), not a single page. However, you can set paragraph styles (`Format > Paragraph Styles > Borders and shading`) with background colors, which should accomplish the same effect:

[image: Borders and shading][image: Format > Paragraph Styles > Borders and shading]

Double-check that bullets and indent inputs work correctly with whatever you choose.

Re: alternatives, full-width tables technically work with the major caveat that tab function will skip to next table cell rather than indenting the line, which is usually a dealbreaker. And there's no way to send a shape to the doc background to write text over it.

Answer (score -2):

Go to page setup then click page color. Then you can change the color.

Comment: But that would be the color throughout the document, isn't? The OP asked if one single page could be colored differently.